# unable to find the right value of input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this jquery script and i am trying to catch the value of input text box with the class "indice". I was able to catch the rel attribute of the button that trigger the event and from there i would like to catch the value of the input text but I cannot get it.. With the code below, it always catch the first element of the page and not the one corresponding to the correct button that trigger the event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cl-button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id =  $(this).attr('rel');
        alert(id);
        var indice = $(this).parent().parent().parent('form').find('.indice').val();
        alert(indice);
        var data_1 = 'id=' + id + '&indice=' + indice;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data_1,
            url: "php/save_index.php"
        })
        .done(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });      
    });
});
```

this is the html:

```
<div class="row g">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid">
        <form class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="border: 0px solid;">
    
            $this->html .= "<div class='col-md-2 h'>";
            $this->html .= "<div class='card'>";
            $this->html .= "<img class='card-img-top' rel= '" . $this->row['id'] . "' src='../" . $this->row['foto'] . "' alt= '' >";
            $this->html .= "</div> <!-- end card -->";
            $this->html .= "</div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->";
    
            $this->html .= "<div class='col-md-2 h'>";
            $this->html .= "<input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='" . $this->row['indice'] . "'>";
            $this->html .= "</div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->";
    
            $this->html .= "<div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>";
            $this->html .= "<div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'>";
            $this->html .= "<a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='" .$this->row['id'] ."'>Salva</a>";
            $this->html .= "</div>";
            $this->html .= "</div><!-- end col-md-2 -->";
  
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"

Browser rendered page:

```
<div class="row g">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid">
    <form class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="border: 0px solid;">

      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='253' src='../gallery/scansione_pagina__raddrizzata-8.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='1'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='253'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='254' src='../gallery/mac-1.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='2'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='254'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='255' src='../gallery/mac-2.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='3'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='255'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='256' src='../gallery/mac-3.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='4'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='256'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='257' src='../gallery/mac-4.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='5'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='257'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add the html that is being rendered by the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cl-button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id =  $(this).attr('rel');
        alert('rel: ' + id);
        var indice = $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.indice').val();
        alert('indice: ' + indice);
        var data_1 = 'id=' + id + '&indice=' + indice;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data_1,
            url: "php/save_index.php"
        })
        .done(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row g">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid">
    <form class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="border: 0px solid;">

      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='253' src='../gallery/scansione_pagina__raddrizzata-8.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='1'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='253'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='254' src='../gallery/mac-1.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='2'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='254'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='255' src='../gallery/mac-2.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='3'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='255'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='256' src='../gallery/mac-3.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='4'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='256'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'>
        <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' rel='257' src='../gallery/mac-4.jpg' alt=''></div> <!-- end card -->
      </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h'><input type='text' class='form-control indice' placeholder='indice' value='5'></div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->
      <div class='col-md-2 h' style='border: 0px solid;'>
        <div class='d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end'><a href='' class='btn btn-primary cl-button' rel='257'>Salva</a></div>
      </div><!-- end col-md-2 -->

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just had to change `$(this).parent().parent().parent('form').find('.indice').val();` to `$(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.indice').val();`

You were going back to the form and finding the `.indice` from there so you were ending up with the first `.induice` instance, you had to be as relevant as possible from the clicked `a` link so I used `prev()` function to find the previous div and find the `.indice` of that div which gave the right instance of `.indice`.

Comment: Yeah!!! you saved my day!!! thanks it works like a charm! :-)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

just use

> var indice = $(this).parents('form').find('.indice').val();

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatly it always return the first element of the page :-(

Comment: $(this).parents('form.d-flex.justify-content-center.align-items-center').find('input.indice').val()

try this

Comment: sure, i edit the original post and insert it?

Comment: i tried the jquery code and the payload answer (in the console) is:

id=253&indice=[object Object]

Comment: sorry I added the wrong link,https://jsfiddle.net/tqbLf9wc/